# Why HTTP method PUT should be idempotent and not the POST in implementation RestFul service?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

There are many resources available over the internet wherein PUT vs POST is discussed. But I could not understand how would that affect the Java implementation or back end implementation which is done underneath for a RestFul service? Links I viewed are mentioned below:

https://www.keycdn.com/support/put-vs-post/

https://spring.io/understanding/REST#post

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/difference-between-put-and-post-in-restful-web-service.html

For example let's say there is a RestFul webservice for Address.
So `POST /addresses` will do the job of updating the Address and `PUT /addresses/1` will do the job of creating the one.
Now how the HTTP method PUT and POST can control what weservice code is doing behind the scenes?

```
PUT /addresses/1
```

may end up creating multiple entries of the same address in the DB.

So my question is, why the idempotent behavior is linked to the HTTP method?

How will you control the idempotent behavior by using specif HTTP methods? Or is it that just a guideline or standard practice suggested?

I am not looking for an explanation of what is idempotent behavior but what make us tag these HTTP methods so?

Comment: Side note: *So POST will do the job of updating the Address and PUT will do the job of creating the one* - It's the opposite. PUT updates, POST creates.

Comment: @BackSlash `PUT` just has the semantics that is should replace the current representation of the invoked endpoint with the one provided in the payload of the request. If there was none available before, PUT can create one which has the effect of creating the actual resource. The semantics of `POST` requests are even more vague by letting the implementor define what a received payload will do. So `PUT updates, POST creates` is not true in general, just the oversimplified view of these operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is HTTP specific. As RFC linked by you states that https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html (see up to date RFC links at the bottom of this answer). It is not described as part of REST: [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)

Now you wrote,

> I am not looking for an explanation of what is idempotent behavior but
> what make us tag these HTTP methods so?

An idempotent operation has always the same result (I know you know it), but the result is not the same thing as the HTTP response. It should be obvious from HTTP perspective that multiple requests with any method even all the same parameters can have different responses (ie. timestamps). So they can actually differ.

What should not change is the result of the operation. So calling multiple times `PUT /addresses/1` **should not** create multiple addresses.

As you see it's called PUT not CREATE for a reason. It may create resource if it does not exist. If it exists then it may overwrite it with the new version (update) if its exactly the same should do nothing on the server and result in the same answer as if it would be the same request (because it may be the same request repeated because the previous request was interrupted and the client did not receive response).

Comparing to SQL PUT would more like `INSERT OR UPDATE` not only `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

> So my question is, why the idempotent behavior is linked to the HTTP method?

It is likned to HTTP method so some services (proxies) know that in case of failure of request they can try safely (not in the terms of safe HTTP method but in the terms of idempotence) repeat them.

> How will you control the idempotent behavior by using specif HTTP methods?

I'm not sure what are you asking for.
But:

- GET, HEAD just return data it does not change anything (apart maybe some logs, stats, metadata?) so it's safe and idempotent.
- POST, PATCH can do anything it is not safe nor idempotent
- PUT, DELETE - are not safe (they change data) but they are idempotent so it is "safe" to repeat them.

This basically means that safe method can be made by proxies, caches, web crawlers etc. safely without changing anything. Idempotent can be repeated by software and it will not change the outcome.

> Or is it that just a guideline or standard practice suggested?

It is "standard". Maybe RFC is not standard yet but it will eventually be one and we don't have anything else we could (and should) follow.

**Edit:**

As RFC mentioned above is outdated here are some references to current RFCs about that topic:

- Retrying idempotent requests by client or proxy: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3.1
- Pipelineing idempotent requests: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3.2
- Idempotent methods in: HTTP https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2

Thanks to [Roman Vottner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925525/why-http-method-put-should-be-idempotent-and-not-the-post-in-implementation-rest/48928148#comment84862663_48928148) for the suggestion.

Comment: Please, use the most recent versions of the HTTP 1.1 spec: [Message Syntax and Routing](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230), [Semantics and Content](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231), [Conditional Requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232), [Range Requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233), [Caching](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234), [Authentication](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235)

Answer (score 4):

> So my question is, why the idempotent behavior is linked to the HTTP method?
> I am not looking for an explanation of what is idempotent behavior but what make us tag these HTTP methods so?

So that generic, domain agnostic participants in the exchange of messages can make useful contributions.

RFC 7231 calls out a specific example in its definition of [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)

> Idempotent methods are distinguished because the request can be repeated automatically if a communication failure occurs before the client is able to read the server's response.  For example, if a client sends a PUT request and the underlying connection is closed before any response is received, then the client can establish a new connection and retry the idempotent request.  It knows that repeating the request will have the same intended effect, even if the original request succeeded, though the response might differ.

A client, or intermediary, doesn't need to know anything about your bespoke API, or its underlying implementation, to act this way.  All of the necessary information is in the specification (RFC 7231's definitions of [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) and [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)), and in the server's announcement that the resource supports PUT.

Note that idempotent request handling is required of PUT, but it is not forbidden for POST.  It's not wrong to have an idempotent POST request handler, or even one that is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).  But *generic* components, that have only the metadata and the HTTP spec to work from, will not know or discover that the POST request handler is idempotent.

> I could not understand how would that affect the Java implementation or back end implementation which is done underneath for a RestFul service?

There's no magic; using PUT doesn't automatically change the underlying implementation of the service;  technically, it doesn't even constrain the underlying implementation.  What it does do is clearly document where the responsibility lies.

It's analogous to [Fielding's 2002 observation](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) about GET being safe

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and
> therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface
> or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that
> causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the
> sake of this definition).

An important thing to realize is that, as far as HTTP is concerned, there is no "resource hierarchy".  There's no relationship between `/addresses` and `/addresses/1` -- for example, messages to one have no effect on cached representations of the other.  The notion that `/addresses` is a "collection" and `/addresses/1` is an "item in the /addresses collection" is an implementation detail, private to the origin server.

(It used to be the case that the semantics of POST would refer to subordinate resources, see for example [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-8.3); but even then the spelling of the identifier for the subordinate was not constrainted.)

> I mean PUT /employee is acceptable or it has to be PUT/employee/<employee-id>

`PUT /employee` has the semantics of "replace the current representation of /employee with the representation I'm providing".  If `/employee` is a representation of a collection, it is perfectly fine to modify that collection by passing with PUT a new representation *of the collection*.

```
GET /collection

200 OK

{/collection/1, collection/2}

PUT /collection

{/collection/1, /collection/2, /collection/3}

200 OK

GET /collection

200 OK

{/collection/1, /collection/2, /collection/3}

PUT /collection

{/collection/4}

200 OK

GET /collection

200 OK

{/collection/4}
```

If that's not what you want; if you want to *append* to the collection, rather than replace the entire representation, then `PUT` has the wrong semantics when applied to the collection.  You either need to PUT the item representation to an item resource, or you need to use some other method on the collection (POST or PATCH are suitable)

```
GET /collection

200 OK

{/collection/1, collection/2}

PUT /collection/3

200 OK

GET /collection

200 OK

{/collection/1, /collection/2, /collection/3}

PATCH /collection

{ op: add, path: /4, ... }

200 OK

GET /collection

200 OK

{/collection/1, /collection/2, /collection/3, /collection/4 }
```

Comment: Will you be able to make your answer more explanatory by using an example such as RestFul service for an Employee. I am not expecting code at all. But what is expected when you do POST/employee and PUT/employee/2? Also does PUT should know about the resource beforehand? I mean PUT/employee is acceptable or it has to be PUT/employee/<employee-id>?

Comment: @Sam Ideally the document type the representation is created for determines what is allowed and what not. Think of HTML. It defines which tags are available as well as the semantics and hints clients on how to perform further requests. The server, of course, has the right to transform the received representation to fit the representation format of the current content or reject the request in general as well. A server following the REST model, will hint clients on how to perform further actions (i.e. like HTML does with forms or similar approaches)

Comment: @Sam `should PUT know about resources beforehand`: Basically a client should not assume that certain resources have a certain type. [Fielding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) referred to this as [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Content type negotiation should be used instead. If a client wants to send data to the server it either gets instructed by the server beforehand or send whatever the mime type specification defines, the server here will then either accept, reject or transform the request

Answer (score 1):

`POST` - is generally not idempotent so that multiple calls will create multiple objects with different IDs

`PUT` - given the id in the URI you would apply "create or update" query to your database thus once the resource is created every next call will make no difference to the backend state

I.e. there is a clear difference in the backend in how you generate new / updated existing stored objects. E.g. assuming you are using MySQL and auto-generated ID:

`POST` will end up as `INSERT` query

`PUT` will end up in `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query

Comment: A common misbeliefe is that HTTP methods POST, GET, PUT, DELETE directly map onto CRUD database features. You can't and probably should not blindly map HTTP operations onto database related instructions. The semantic of POST is completely up to the implementor and thus it is not required to insert a new record into a database table. It might even remove some statements or do nothing at all. Further, HTTP at its core is used to manage files on remote machines. Any business logic you deduct from any document modification is merely a side-effect of the document managment.

Comment: @RomanVottner original question was about what might be the difference in backend implementation thus I gave an example of what that could be

Answer (score 1):

> How will you control the idempotent behavior by using specific HTTP
> methods? Or is it that just a guideline or standard practice
> suggested?

It is more about the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and an app must follow these specifications. Nothing stops you from altering the behavior on the server side.
There is always a difference between the web service and a Restful Web service.

Consider some legacy apps which uses servlets. Servlets used to have `doGet` and `doPost` methods. `doPost` was always recommended for security reasons and storing data on server/db over `doGet`. as the info is embedded in the request it self  and is not exposed to the outer worlds.

Even there nothing stops you to save data in `doGet` or return some static pages in `doPost` hence it's all about following underlying specs

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, why the idempotent behavior is linked to the HTTP method?

Because the HTTP specifications says so:

> 4.2.2.  Idempotent Methods

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on
> the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the
> same as the effect for a single such request.  Of the request methods
> defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods
> are idempotent.

(Source: [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2))

Why do the specs say this?

- Because is useful for implementing HTTP based systems to be able to distinguish idempotent and non-idempotent requests.  And the "method" type provides a good way to make the distinction.
- Because other parts of the HTTP specification are *predicated* on being able to distinguish idempotent methods; e.g. proxies and caching rules.

> How will you control the idempotent behavior by using specif HTTP methods?

It is up to the server to implement PUT & DELETE to have idempotent behavior.  If a server doesn't, then it is *violating* the HTTP specification.

> Or is it that just a guideline or standard practice suggested?

It is *required* behavior.

Now you could ignore the requirement (there are no protocol police!) but if you do, it is liable to cause your systems to break.  Especially if you need to integrate them with systems implemented by other people ... who might write their client code assuming that if it replays a PUT or DELETE that your server won't say "error".

---

In short, we use specifications like HTTP so that our systems are interoperable.  But this strategy only works properly if everyone's code implements the specifications correctly.

Comment: Can I say that PUT ---> Create / Replace and POST --> Update / Create?

Comment: No.  Strictly speaking, POST can't do update.  Also there is no real distinction between update and replace.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest/18243587#18243587

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Rest APIs. We used

POST - Add data
GET  - get data 
PUT  - update data
DELETE - delete data

Read below post to get more idea.

[REST API Best Practices](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2014/04/rest-api-best-practices-http-and-crud.html)